# Haromonise spatial resolution of two datasets with disagg command in R

Tags: r, raster, terra

I have two raster datasets. Dataset 1 is coarser (0.5 resolution) than dataset 2 (0.083 resolution). I need to harmonise them, and bring dataset 1 to dataset 2 (as dataset 1 is coarser). I need to do this using the disagg command, using the method "near".

The command I tried is:

```
harmonised_data <- disagg(dataset1, dataset2, method="near", filename="merged_data"). I get the following error:
# Error: not compatible with requested type: [type=s4, target=double].
```

If someone has a solution, would be great, thank you!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: I don't have any examples of the desired output and I am unfortunately not able to provide sample data because it is currently confidential, sorry!

Comment: Sample data does not mean *your data*. It means any little datasets that can be used to run the code. See e.g., all the R help files, such as  `?terra::disagg`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `disagg` shows

```
?disagg

## S4 method for signature 'SpatRaster'
disagg(x, fact, method="near", filename="", ...)
```

where `x` is a "SpatRaster" and `fact` is a "positive integer". You are using a "SpatRaster" for argument `fact`. Hence the error.

What you can do is something like this

```
0.5 / 0.08333333
[1] 6

h <- disagg(dataset1, 6)
```

You could also do

```
r <- resample(dataset1, dataset2)
```